# angular $resource receive extra information

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am using ng-resource to do ajax request. I want to send extra info besides the data.

For example, I have an article entity on my server

```
exports.fetchArticle = function(req, res, next) {
    var article = req.article
    return res.json({data: article, message: 'success fetch article'})
}
```

The reason I wrap it is that, in the case of deletion, it makes no sense to send data, I can just `return res.json({data: null, message: 'deleted successfully'})`

on my client side, I have:

```
        $scope.fetchArticle = function() {
            Article.get({articleId: $routeParams.articleId}, function(response) {
                $scope.article = response.data
                $scope.ajaxSuccess = response.message
            }, function(err) {
                $scope.ajaxError = err.data.message
            })
        }
```

$scope.article is not an instance of ng-resource anymore, thus I can't do further request with $scope.article, i.e. this will cause error, since $scope.article is a plain json object:

```
            $scope.article.$update(function(response) {...})
```

If I simply `return res.json(article)` from server, it works, but I can't send along the message.

The reason I dont generate the message from client but fetch from server is that, the error message is from server, I want to keep success message consistent with the error message.

Is there any other elegant way to send the message?

Comment: On the client, do you need to store the message together with the reponse data, or do you just do the same thing with the message all the time? (like logging it)

Comment: I display the message to the user like 'update success'. I could just create it from client but since the error message is from server, i prefer to get the success message from server as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that **all** your servers responses follow this format:

```
{ 
    data: {/*...*/},
    message: 'some message'
}
```

You could use [`$http`'s `transformResponse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses) for that, so that you get an ngResource instance that **is** your returned object while still processing your message. For that, you need a transform-function:

```
function processMessage(data, message) {
    //Do whatever you want with your message here, like displaying it
}

function transform(response) {
    processMessage(response.data,response.message);

    var data = response.data;

    delete response.data;
    delete response.message;

    for(var attributeName in data) {
        response[attributeName] = data[attributeName];
    }

    return response;
}
```

Then you can add this function to `$http`'s default transfroms in the `config` of your app:

```
angular.module("yourApp",[/* ... */])
    .config(function($httpProvider){
        //....all your other config

        $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.unshift(transform);
    });
```

Now all repsonses from `$http` get transformed by this function, triggering `processMessage` and leaving you with a ngResource instance of the returned object.